# How to split a string having [] as delimiters in java

Tags: java, string

I want to remove `[ ]` braces from the below string-
`"[maths=100, english=20]"`

I have tried doing it in following ways but in both the trials it is not removing the end `]` brace.

**Approach 1:**

```
String[] metrics= "[maths=100, english=20]";
String[] value = metrics[1].split("\\[");
String[] finalValue = value[1].split("\\]");
System.out.println(finalValue[0]);  // this should give string as maths=100, english=20
```

**Approach 2:**

```
String[] metrics= "[maths=100, english=20]";
String[] value = metrics[1].split("\\[\\]");
System.out.println(finalValue[1]);  // this should give string as maths=100, english=20
```

Can anyone guide me where i am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to trim and clean your data then you can do a simple check and substring.

```
String input = ...;
String cleanedInput = input.trim();
if (cleanedInput.startsWith("[") && cleanedInput.endsWith("]")) {
    cleanedInput = cleanedInput.substring(1, cleanedInput.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(cleanedInput);
}
```

---

If you're wanting to match and capture from a larger set of data then you can use RegEx patterns with capture groups to match and capture the data you want.

For parsing a proper document structure though you should try to use a real parser but if you truly are just trying to match and capture some simple data then RegEx will often be ok.

```
String input = ...;
// RegEx pattern "\[([^\[\]]*)\]" anything inside braces except other braces
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\[\\]]*)\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern .matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String data = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
String metrics= "[maths=100, english=20]";
String[] split = metrics.split("\\[|]");
System.out.println(split[1]);
```

it prints
"maths=100, english=20"

Or you can simply replace all [ and ] character

```
String metrics = "[maths=100, english=20]";
metrics = metrics.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
System.out.println(metrics);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the braces like this:

```
String s = "[maths=100, english=20]";
s = s.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
System.out.println(s);
```